# Using data received from Arduino via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am working on an Android app that will constantly receive data from an Arduino HC-05 and store it in a database. For now I am focusing on receiving the data properly (so just displaying it on the screen is my next step).

I have followed [this guide](http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring14/group01/docs/appnote/Wirsing-SendingAndReceivingDataViaBluetoothWithAnAndroidDevice.pdf) (PDF) to setup a basic app that will receive data from the Arduino. However, it doesn't include a section about using the received data. I've tried adding two lines of code to the `handleMessage` function in order to display the received data on screen, but I don't see any difference in the textview (it stays "Hello World!").

I know that my Arduino is sending the data just fine, since on another app called "Serial Bluetooth Terminal" it is displayed properly. Here is the code for the Handler class:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
        int begin = (int)msg.arg1;
        int end = (int)msg.arg2;

        switch(msg.what) {
            case 1:
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                writeMessage = writeMessage.substring(begin, end);
                // 2 lines of code I've added here:
                TextView tempTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
                tempTextView.setText(writeMessage);
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Aside from the 2 lines, the code is basically the same as the final stage of the guide. And here is the code for the Arduino (which currently just sends "1 2.00 3.00" over and over):

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(0, 1); //RX|TX
int Temp=  1;
float Ph = 2;
float Ec = 3;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BTSerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(Temp);
  Serial.print(" ");
  delay(100);
  Serial.print(Ph);
  Serial.print(" ");
  delay(100);
  Serial.print(Ec);
  Serial.print(" ");
  delay(100);
  Serial.print('\n');
  if(Serial.available())
    BTSerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

Comment: `SoftwareSerial BTSerial(0, 1); //RX|TX` --- nononono 0,1 is Serial. Do not run SoftwareSerial on D0/D1.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you elaborate?
(I don't understand much about arduino, this is some code my friend wrote for the testings)